# Cannot access file after downloading it with Webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webclient, ioexception

I have downloaded a zip file using this code from a web server:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(url, savePath);
```

Then, in another method, during the same session I try and extract the file with this method:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractDir);
```

This throws the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 
'C:\ProgramData\ZipFile.zip' because it is being used by another process.'
```

If I restart the program then unzip the file (without redownloading it) it extracts without any problem.

This doesn't make much sense to me because the `Webclient client` is located in another method and hence should be destroyed...

There is nothing else accessing that file other than the 2 lines of code provided above.

Is there any way to free the file?

Comment: Please show a more complete code example (e.g. the true relationship between the method that downloads the file, the method that extracts the file, how they are each called, and any initialization of the `WebClient` if any).

Comment: `DownloadFile` instead `DownloadFileAsync`, its slove the problem? if yes, you need add await keyword and the zip extract it happen only after the download end.

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the files when the download completed, to do this, you need to use **DownloadFileCompleted** event of **webclient**

```
private void DownloadPackageFromServer(string downloadLink)
    {
        ClearTempFolder();
        var address = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl + downloadLink);

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            _downloadLink = downloadLink;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(address, GetLocalFilePath(downloadLink));
            wc.Dispose();
        }
    }



 private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 

        UnZipDownloadedPackage(_downloadLink); 
    }

 private void UnZipDownloadedPackage(string downloadLink)
    {
        var fileName = GetLocalFilePath(downloadLink);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, Constants.TemporaryMusicFolderPath);
    }
```